# How to use bitmap resources in ASP.NET Core app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use a couple of bitmap resources within `.netcore2.1` app but when I add an image resource to my project it shows the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Resource 'sign_here_tag' could not be instantiated.  Type System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51 cannot be located.

I have `system.drawing.common` NuGet package installed within my project, but the error's still coming up.

after installing CoreCompat.System.Drawing i still have this error coming up:
[image]

Even if i change the file extension to wav(to force it to add it as a MemoryStream) i still get the error:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

To use namespace `System.Drawing` in ASP.NET Core, I suggest you to install this package:

[CoreCompat.System.Drawing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreCompat.System.Drawing/)

> Install-Package CoreCompat.System.Drawing -Version 1.0.0-beta006

*(Of course, removing all reference(s) that you've tried before installing this package)*

After installing, you can use `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and `System.Drawing.Image` as normally.

**NOTE:** If you want to use this package in class library, make sure the library is using `.NET Standard`

Comment: I got the same result using this package, i've updated the question to show the error

Comment: @AnKing Have you tried to remove reference `System.Drawing.Common`? You should try again with my suggestion: *removing all reference(s) that you've tried before installing this package*

Comment: In my solution explorer I only have reference to SDK (Microsoft.NETCore.App(2.1)) which contains System.Drawing.dll But I'm not sure how to remove this reference without removing the entire sdk. is there a trick to it?

Comment: @AnKing You can create new project (for testing) and install this package. Code, build and run. If it works, the problem may come from another place.

Comment: I just created a new project and was able to add resource without any problems. It goes right into "images" section of the resources. So there must be  in issue with visual studio not finding system.drawing.bitmap for that particular project for some reason

Comment: @AnKing In that case, I recommend you copy all the code in the current project to the new project. Then, deleting the current project.

Comment: I was trying to avoid this, since the project has grown and is now too big for this kind of manipulations :(

Comment: @AnKing You create new project as a library that the main project can refer to. I suggest to create .NET Standard class library. Copy all the code from the main project that using `System.Drawing` to this library. BTW, you can continue with the main project.

Comment: Better not to use it as it is moved to legacy.