# .Net Core unable to use Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-2.1

I am working on a Web Service using .Net Core 2.1.

I have a byte array containing all pixels values (in grey scale), a width, a height. I want to create a bitmap from theses parameters.

There is my code (from a working .Net Framework 4 project) :

```
public FileResult PostSealCryptItem(Byte[] matrix, int width, int height)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(ToArgb(matrix, x, y)));

    Byte[] data = BitmapToByteArray(bmp);
    FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult(data , "image/png");

    return result;
}
```

But in .NET Core, I've the error :

> The type or namespace name 'Bitmap' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've try to add reference to System.Drawing but it did not work.

Comment: There is no built in image manipulation in .NET Core, you need to use a third party tool, but there are some good ones. For example I'm currently using [SkiaSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/skiasharp).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use bitmap resources in ASP.NET Core app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341354/how-to-use-bitmap-resources-in-asp-net-core-app)

Comment: There's [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common)

Comment: @stuartd Downside of that is that you are limited to running on Windows I believe?

Comment: @DavidG looks like it, now I see it has `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents` as a dependency

Comment: you could use the windows compatibility pack. Guess you have to stick with windows then... https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoYouUseSystemDrawingInNETCore.aspx

Comment: @stuartd Yeah, that's why I wouldn't recommend using it. Especially considering `SkiaSharp` and `ImageSharp` both do everything (and more). Skia also supports webp which can be useful.

Comment: Do read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing#remarks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`Bitmap` is part of `System.Drawing` which was included in .Net Framework.

It is no longer included with .net core and must be added manually.

Install the Nuget package `System.Drawing.Common` by right-clicking on your project in visual studio and choosing `Manage Nuget Packages`

In the Nuget Package manager, click on the `Browse Tab`, search for `System.Drawing.Common` in the top and it should be the first Package, official by Microsoft. It will work just as in .Net Framework:
[image]

Comment: Just a note for those who will come here later - as for net 6 the `System.Drawing.Common` package considered to be Windows-only and can not be used on Mac or Linux anymore (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only)

Comment: How to make it supported for linux as well?

Answer (score 4):

You can use ImageSharp instead of System.Drawing

https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp

Nuget console

```
Install-Package SixLabors.ImageSharp -Version 1.0.0-beta0005
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a NuGet package instead of System.Drawing, you can use it

```
Install-Package System.Drawing.Common
```

Answer (score 2):

[Aspose.Drawing](https://products.aspose.com/drawing/net) is a drop-in cross-platform replacement for System.Drawing. The library is fully managed and supports Web Services using .Net Core 2.1. (I'm one of the developers.)

Comment: Is that a commercial product ?

Comment: @beppe9000 Yes.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me
`dotnet add package System.Drawing.Common --version 5.0.3`